# Empty space at the bottom of page on resolutions higher than 1024x768

Tags: html, css

The web page I'm trying to design only seems to fit 1024x768 resolutions. When the resolution is higher there is a large amount of empty space at the bottom of the screen. I'm fairly new to CSS, but I'm pretty sure the error has something to do with the lack of a position property. I either want the footer and main div to go to the bottom of the screen, or for the page to scale. If someone could tell me what I'm missing, I'd be eternally grateful.

http://www.eightbitbastards.com/8bbtest/index.html

Comment: Add a JSFiddle ^-^ or a bit of code that you've tried to play with.

Comment: Try declaring `height:100%` on the `html`, `body` and `#wrapper` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Use 100% height on html & body AND use 100% on wrapper including absolute positioning on elements, ie:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
    background-image: url("../images/bg-repeat.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 768px;
    position: relative;
}

#main {
    bottom: 21px; /* lifting it up 21px from bottom to allow for footer slotting in */
    height: auto;
    left: 0; /* change accordingly to left position */
    min-height: 309px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 768px;
}
```

Then you also want the footer to remain at the bottom - set it to absolute positioning with bottom at 0.
Also, I'd use classes within `#wrapper` rather than id's.

Comment: The `HTML` element should be resized to 100% height as well, i.e. `html, body { height: 100%; }`

Comment: I tried and it seemed as if nothing changed :c. Thanks for tryin' though.

Comment: Will revise my answer in 2 mninutes.

Answer (score 0):

Add the background that is on your wrapper div to the body of the page.

```
body {
     background-image: url(http://www.eightbitbastards.com/8bbtest/images/bg-repeat.png);
     background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

Comment: While I appreciate the help, this isn't what I'm trying to achieve ^^; I want the wrapper to fit the resolution and bring the footer and main divs to the bottom with it.